# Filters of GlobalFilterCollection run before Filters of ControllerInstanceFilterProvider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-filters

I came across a weird behavior but I am not sure if I am on the right track here.

I have a controller which overrides `OnException` method of the `Controller` base class.

```
public class ControllerFiltersController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {

        Trace.TraceInformation(
            "ControllerFiltersController Exception: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")
        );
    }
}
```

I also have an custom ExceptionFilter as follows:

```
public class HandleErrorCustom : IExceptionFilter {

    public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext) {

        Trace.TraceInformation(
            "HandleErrorCustom Exception Message: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff")
        );
    }
}
```

Then, I registered it as a global filter:

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {

    filters.Add(new HandleErrorCustom());
}
```

What I expected is here for the *controller instance filter* to run before global filter since the order of filters which are provided by `ControllerInstanceFilterProvider` is `Int32.MinValue` and the scope of them is `FilterScope.First`.

As also explained here: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Service Location, Part 4: Filters](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/07/service-location-pt4-filters.html)

But the result is different:

> iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : HandleErrorCustom Exception Message:
>   06:56:49.972
>
> iisexpress.exe Information: 0 : ControllerFiltersController Exception:
>   06:56:49.974

This is an ASP.NET MVC 4 application and I am not aware of any changes which effects the filter ordering behavior of ASP.NET MVC 3. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

Filter ordering depends on the direction the information is flowing. If the information is flowing into the action, then the order is as you expect it; if the information is flowing back out of the action, then the order is reversed.

For example, assume you have three filters in this order: F1, F2, F3. Assume that these are action filters (meaning, they're listening to ActionExecuting and ActionExecuted). The order the system will run them is as follows:

```
F1.ActionExecuting()
F2.ActionExecuting()
F3.ActionExecuting()
Action()
F3.ActionExecuted()
F2.ActionExecuted()
F1.ActionExecuted()
```

Error handlers are, by definition, filters that run on the return-side of actions, so their order is reversed.

Comment: Now, I got it. So, the filters, which has the lower value and run on the return-side of actions, will run first. Thanks!